# How to convert image black and white image to 0 - 1 byte array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, bit

I'm trying to convert an `.BMP` pic into `byte[]` or `byte[][]`. I already try 2 solutions and i get strange results

First :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.qr);
int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] byt = buffer.array();
```

In the `byt` i get array with over 36 000 element and all have `-1` value.

My second try was :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.qr);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,stream);
byte[] byteArrat = stream.toByteArray();
```

But now i have array with over 1200 elements which look random ( value form -180 to 100 )

Is there any possible to mage bmp to array which have 0 for `WHITE` color and 1 for `BLACK` ? Already i'm stock and don't know what to do. The pic :

[image: Image to decode]

Answer (score 1):

PNG is an encoded format so it won't be straightforward to analyze that as an array, so go with your first instinct.

This image is 210x210, so you should expect 44100 different color values. Android doesn't know that it's black and white, so you're going to get full color values for each pixel and will need to convert those to simple 0s and 1s.

See the [getPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method which might be more straightforward for your use case. It will dump the pixel colors into an `int[]` argb array where you can then simplify into black vs white.